# Eclipse: change description of variable in debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, variables

Can I change description of variable?
[image: eclipse debug variables]

I want to see my own string at this place. I want generate this string by myself.
For example

```
"RTKAccount number=111 and FGSFDS"
```

insead of

```
"RTKAccount (id=830039244504)".
```

I tried to change `toString()` method in my class, but it did not work.

```
public String toString() {
    return "RTKAccount id=" + this.id + " number=" + this.number;
}
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, *at least to me*. Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: Have you tried clicking on that plus sign at the left of the array members to see the fields of each object?

Comment: I tried clicking on that plus, but it is not what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're searching for are the **detail formatters**.

Right-click on the variable in the *Variable* view and select *"New Detail Formatter..."*. In the wizard type this into the big text area:

```
"RTKAccount id=" + id + " number=" + number
```

And there you have it ;-)

Comment: That only changes the content of the detail section at the bottom of the variables tab. I think the content of the Value column can not be changed for custom object instances.

Comment: Oh, you mean @Alexmelyon wants to change the text next to the variables? I don't know if that can be solved easily (well, probably someone already wrote a plugin for that, but one can easily develop it too). Thx for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value of a variable by right clicking it -> Change value

Comment: Unfortunately, it works only for [0] element, but not for other.